# Rounding to Previous 2 hour Window Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm trying to round a date (date datatype which includes timestamp too) to the previous 2 hour block. e.g 13:23 -> 12:00, 18:12 -> 18:00

I had it working in MySQL using a MOD function as:

```
DATE_ADD(DATE(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL - 7 HOUR)), INTERVAL HOUR(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL - 6 HOUR)) - MOD(HOUR(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL - 6 HOUR)), 2) HOUR) AS Window_Start
```

**Complexity added as I'm also shifting the time a) to correct for a 7 hr time zone difference and b) because I need to offset the time by 1 hr before grouping it. But that's not where the issue is.

But I can't get it to work on an Oracle platform. Specifically, I can't seem to extract the hour of the time as a number which to feed into the MOD(). I've been trying with CAST, and TO_TIMESTAMP and TO_CHAR but nothing seems to work. The usual error is "inconsistent datatypes".

EXTRACT only works with with timestamp type, not date. And TO_TIMESTAMP only works on strings. But EXTRACT(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR( doesn't work either.

I'm sure there's an easier way to do this...

Comment: Hour portion of a value of date data type can be extracted using `to_char()` function with `hh` or `hh24` format element as in `to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'hh24'))`. Use `to_number()` function to explicitly convert result of the conversion to numeric data type.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, one method is using date arithmetic.  For example:

```
select date '2000-01-01' + floor((sysdate - date '2000-01-01') * (24 / 2)) / (24 / 2)
from dual;
```

The "24" is for hours in a day.  The "2" is for the two hour period you want to truncate to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the answer but it'll give you a rabbit hole to chase:

```
select sysdate as curr_dt, to_date(to_char(sysdate - interval '2' hour, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24')) as two_hours_ago from dual;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To get the hour in a number format this will work.

select TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH')) from dual

You can select each piece individually using the time stamp portion of this date format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I wrote this generic function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MakeInterval(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END MakeInterval;
```

In your case the usage would be

```
SELECT MakeInterval(created_at, INTERVAL '2' HOUR) 
FROM ...
```

But perhaps this would be an overkill in your situation, usage without the function would be:

```
SELECT TRUNC(created_at) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) / 2) * 2 * INTERVAL '1' HOUR
FROM ...
```